Need to change default spell check from US to UK system wide via group policy
One of our sites has US spell check on by default, I want to change this so that it uses UK instead. Is there a setting in group policy that would help with this? Preferably I need it system wide, but can change it for each application in necessary.
Cheers

First, you need to identify what the setting is. Is it a registry value? Is it a file? You need to identify the application and all the other omitted information.
